# How to run a process in a multiuser environment

Tags: c#, multithreading, process

I  running a process for doing some task. Suppose 10 person are requesting to run that process then what will happen?
Whether it will maintain a queue or ?
I am writing the program in C#.
Any answers will be appreciated :)

Comment: "Requesting to run that process" What do you mean? Each person who starts (exec) that process gets an instance which is separate from the others. Or are you talking about some network queue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a simple Application, windows will always create a new process and load the executable within this place.

To have a single application which will get notified if the same user starts the same application a second time you can use [the SingleInstance approach](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode31SingleInstanceWinFormsAndMicrosoftVisualBasicdll.aspx).

If you want that several users on the same machine will use the same instance you need to break down another fence. This can be achieved by using a windows service. In this case every user start it's own GUI (maybe using the SingleInstance behaviour) and this GUI will sync the showing up task list with a running service in the background.
Further infos about writing services you find an [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=windows+service), [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+windows+service&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) or at [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984074.aspx).